# elasticsearch mapping is empty after creating

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an autocomplete index for my elasticsearch using the search_as_you_type datatype.
My first command I run is

```
curl --request PUT 'https://elasticsearch.company.me/autocomplete' \
 '{
   "mappings": {
       "properties": {
           "company_name": {
               "type": "search_as_you_type"
           },
           "serviceTitle": {
               "type": "search_as_you_type"
           }
       }
   }
}'
```

which returns

```
{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true,"index":"autocomplete"}curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 18:
{
   "mappings": {
       "properties": etc.the rest of the json object I created}}
```

Then I reindex using

```
curl --silent --request POST 'http://elasticsearch.company.me/_reindex?pretty' --data-raw '{
 "source": {
   "index": "existing_index"
 },
 "dest": {
   "index": "autocomplete"
 }
}' | grep "total\|created\|failures"
```

I expect to see some `"total":1000,"created":5`etc but some kind of response from the terminal, but I get nothing. Also, when I check the mapping of my autocomplete index, by running `curl -u thething 'https://elasticsearch.company.me/autocomplete/_mappings?pretty'`,
I get an empty mapping result:

```
{
  "autocomplete" : {
    "mappings" : { }
  }
}
```

Is my error in the creation of my index or the reindexing? I'm expecting the autocomplete mappings to show the two fields I'm searching for, ie: "company_name" and "serviceTitle". Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Remove the `grep` after your reindex command. What do you get?

Comment: @Brian Guan: Did you get the solution as I'm also facing it for older elasticsearch version 5.3.0

Comment: @RPaul It was actually an error in my JSON body, had an extra {
I highly recommend doing this all in Postman so you can skip all the --request or --silent stuff, and just add the json object into the body part of postman - there it will automatically detect errors in your JSON vs in cURL you have no way of knowing.